# Declaring input/output streams from socket preventing program from continuing

Tags: java, sockets, io, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

Alright, so I've coded what is going to be a simple communication program using a server, really as a test more than anything else, so I know it's missing a lot, but with the following Client class:

```
public class Client {
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;

    private Socket socket;

    private String server;
    private int port;

    public Client(String ip, int p){
        port = p;
        server = ip;
    }

    public boolean start(){
        try{
            socket = new Socket(server, port);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        try{
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("All declared");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;}
        new LThread().start();
        return true;
    }

    private void sendMessage(Message msg){
        try{
        out.writeObject(msg);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int portNum = 1500;
        String servers = "localhost";

        Client client = new Client(servers, portNum);

        System.out.println("Client started");

        if(!client.start()){
            System.out.println("Didn't work");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Client started again");


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true){
            String i = scan.nextLine();
            client.sendMessage(new Message(2, i));
        }
    }

    class LThread extends Thread{

        public void run(){
            System.out.println("Lthread running");
            while(true){
                try{
                    String message = (String)in.readObject();
                    System.out.println(message);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The program simply stops when it reaches the point at which it declares its `ObjectInput` and `Output` `Stream`s. The program doesn't exit, it doesn't appear to enter the `catch` block, and I cannot, at all, figure out what on earth could possibly be causing it. The line "All declared." is never printed, but anything before it is printed. Could anyone please tell me why my program just ceases to function at this point without displaying any errors?

EDIT: I figure that there could be an error somewhere in my Server file, so here's the class:

```
public class Server {

    private static int uid;

    private ArrayList<ClientThread> clients;
    private int port;
    private boolean cont;

    public Server(int p){
        port = p;
        clients = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
    }

    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Started");
        cont = true;
        try{
            ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Declared socket");
            while(cont){
                Socket sk = srvr.accept();
                System.out.println("Socket accepted");

                if(!cont)break;

                ClientThread t = new ClientThread(sk);
                clients.add(t);
                t.start();
            }
            try{
                srvr.close();
                for(ClientThread t : clients){
                    t.in.close();
                    t.out.close();
                    t.socket.close();
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void broadcast(String msg){
        for(int i=clients.size(); --i >= 0;){
            ClientThread t= clients.get(i);
                if(!t.writeMsg(msg)){
                    clients.remove(i);
                }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int portNum = 1500;

        Server server = new Server(portNum);
        server.start();
    }

    class ClientThread extends Thread{
        Socket socket;
        ObjectInputStream in;
        ObjectOutputStream out;
        String name;
        int id;
        Message m;

        ClientThread(Socket s){
            id = ++uid;
            socket = s;
            try{
                System.out.println("Before");
                in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println("After");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        public void run(){
            boolean c = true;
            while(c){
                try{
                    m = (Message)in.readObject();
                    switch(m.getType()){
                    case 2:
                        broadcast(m.getMessage());
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }

        public boolean writeMsg(String msg){
            if(!socket.isConnected()){
                return false;
            }
            try{
                out.writeObject(msg);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();}
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Alright, another edit. So I added those two `println`s to the `try` statement in `ClientThread`'s constructor, and, just like with client, it runs until I try to initialize the streams, and then it just stops. Again, no errors, no anything; it just completely stops in its tracks. I cannot figure out why on earth this happens, but if it means anything, I'm using the Eclipse IDE to run it.

Comment: Just a tip: the two lines above the one that prints "All declared" don't declare anything.

Comment: How do you know it's not stuck in `new Socket(server, port)`?

Comment: @immibis Right, but changing the output to "All assigned." won't really make the code run any better.

Comment: @immibis I've removed it because I've figured out what I needed to from that line, but I added a line to output something to the console immediately after `new Socket(server, port)`, and it properly printed to the console each time I ran it, so I'm pretty sure that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I snagged on this the first time I used *ObjectInputStream* and *ObjectOutputStream*.  At the root cause of your problem is within the [constructor *ObjectInputStream*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream(java.io.InputStream)).  The constructor will read from the underlying stream in an attempt to get header information such as the wire format version.

In order to prevent your client and server from infinity waiting for the other to send the information first, you should invert the order of the input and output streams, then flush the output stream explicitly.  The following at the construction of the streams in the client and server will fix your problem:

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.flush();
in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```